# Using switch statement in before block of cypress tests

Tags: cypress

I am trying to run switch block or some other way to achieve this if/else condition

```
students.forEach((Product) => {     // List of products I am iterating 
       before(() => {
           switch (ProductID) {
               case 5175125:
                   pirce = 371;  //  I am trying to achieve switch block where based on product ID price is assigned.
                   break;
           }
        cy.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: `/v1/Auth/token/token`
        }).its('body').then(function (response) {
            token = JSON.parse(response)
            token = token['accessToken']
            return token['accessToken']
        }).as('authToken')
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable outside of your loop, like so:

```
let price;
students.forEach((Product) => { 
    if (Product.ID === 5175125) {
       price = 371;
    }

    // price is now 371

    cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `/v1/Auth/token/token`
    }).its('body').then(function (response) {
        token = JSON.parse(response)
        token = token['accessToken']
        return token['accessToken']
    }).as('authToken')
});
```